# Duplicate column name [Error number: 1060] - PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatable, mysql-error-1060

Why I get #1060 - Duplicate column name 'id_btp' ?

This is my code

```
public function json(){
    $this->load->library('datatables');
    $this->datatables->select('b.nama_btp, c.nama_bahan, d.nama_senyawa, e.cara_pengolahan, f.nama_kategori, a.batas_maksimum');
    $this->datatables->from('t_pangan a');
    $this->datatables->join('t_btp b', 'b.id_btp=a.id_btp');
    $this->datatables->join('t_bahan c', 'c.id_bahan=a.id_bahan');
    $this->datatables->join('t_senyawa d', 'd.id_senyawa=a.id_senyawa');
    $this->datatables->join('t_pengolahan e', 'e.id_pengolahan=a.id_pengolahan');
    $this->datatables->join('t_kategori f', 'f.id_kategori=a.id_kategori');
    return print_r($this->datatables->generate());
}
```

This is the error message

```
Error Number: 1060

Duplicate column name 'id_btp'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `t_pangan` `a` JOIN `t_btp` `b` ON `b`.`id_btp`=`a`.`id_btp` JOIN `t_bahan` `c` ON `c`.`id_bahan`=`a`.`id_bahan` JOIN `t_senyawa` `d` ON `d`.`id_senyawa`=`a`.`id_senyawa` JOIN `t_pengolahan` `e` ON `e`.`id_pengolahan`=`a`.`id_pengolahan` JOIN `t_kategori` `f` ON `f`.`id_kategori`=`a`.`id_kategori`) SqueryAux
```

I did not select all the attributes (`select *`), but why does the error message indicate that I selected all attributes?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: somewhere `id_btp` is conflicting with other. It is considering the same in tables.

Comment: @NomanJaved But I didn't select all the attributes (`select *`) including `id_btp`.